# How can I get my loops to display horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: java

How can I get my loops to display horizontally instead of vertically like the below example using JAVA?

[image: Java coding]

**CODE**

```
int i;

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("+"); System.out.printf("%n");
}

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("-");System.out.printf("%n");
}
```

**OUTPUT (Trying to get this to output horizontally instead of vertically)**

```
+
+
+
-
-
-
```

Comment: just remove the `System.out.printf("%n");` part?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int i;

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("+"); 
}
System.out.println();

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("-");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a new line in each loop iteration.

Remove the `System.out.printf("%n");` completely and add a `System.out.println()` between your too loops.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with printing the Newline character, but you're doing it inside of your loop, which is why you print a Newline character everytime you're printing your operator strings. Also, you can just outprint an empty line instead of printing the Newline character.

Try this:

```java
int i;

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("+"); 
}

System.out.println();

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    System.out.print("-");
}
```